# how to detect Facebook / Instagram / Twitter browser?

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, media-queries, instagram

I was wondering if there's a media query and/or a js to detect those browsers specifically.

I'm using a js which is working badly on those browsers because of the different height of the viewport (see the bar in the upper part)

Comment: FYI [tag:java] and [tag:javascript] are *completely different languages*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no media query for browser detection.

Please note that browser detection is not a good practice. Instead, try to use [feature detection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

In your specific case it seems that the viewport is different across browsers and you want to react to this. In the js file you can read this viewport height from the [`window.innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) and then do whatever logic you need.